how to add a confidence layer to my unet model and then use it to regularize loss for an image to image translation task?
to add confidence map to my network and then use it to regularize loss i added a confidence layer at the end of the network and applied it before making the final predictions.
this is the confidence module i use:
# Add a second output for confidence map
        self.confidence_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(filters[0], out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  # 2-channel confidence map
            nn.Sigmoid()  # Confidence values between 0 and 1
        )

and this is how i applied it to the last layer before the final prediction:
x10 = self.up_residual_conv3(x9)
        self.check_for_nan(x10, "After up_residual_conv3")

        prediction = self.output_layer(x10)
        self.check_for_nan(prediction, "After output layer")
        #adding this confidence layer at the end to see if it can improve results
        confidence_map = self.confidence_layer(x10)
        # Return both the prediction and the confidence map
        return prediction, confidence_map

and then this is how i weighted the loss with the confidence map:
   loss_per_pixel = criterion(predictions, targets)
    
    epsilon = 1e-6
    weighted_loss = (confidence_map + epsilon) * loss_per_pixel

but it ruins the networks performance(both quantitative and qualitative). It introduces artifacts to the generated images. What could be wrong?
I added an epsilon value to prevent the gradient from vanishing when the confidence is zero. However, I did not observe much change compared to the situation where I did not include the epsilon. This could be due to how I implemented the confidence layer in the architecture or how I regularized the loss with the confidence, or perhaps both.
but what changes should be useful to make here?

The first row is input, 2nd row is the model's prediction, 3rd row is the ground truth and the final row is just an image for us to give us clue what are in those 3rd rows. The first three rows are grayish color because it is the image difference of the same scene but with two different filters. Adding the confidence loss as a wrapper for my loss causes two things to happen:

introducing artifact
making the images brighter than the ground truth (so it changed image brightness which is not desired)

